# presentViewController in iPhone5s

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, 64-bit

I have created a object MFMailComposeViewController for displaying the mail composer, it working on all 32bit devices but when I run it on iPhone5s it just displayed and dismisses automatically showing error,

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for < UITabBarController: 0xcc7f8f0>.
```

There is tabbar controller that is root of window and I am trying present the mail view on self.
I have tried everything but not able to findout why its not working on iPhone5s.
Let me know if anyone also faces the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the solution I found was to remove the following UIAppearance setting that I had:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -1.0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Hope that helps!

-Stephen

Comment: I have solved my problem using the same way, but forget post as answer here. Thanks mate for posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**"The unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions"**

occurs when you try and display a new viewcontroller before the current view controller is finished displaying. You can reproduce it by navigating in viewWillAppear.

Basically you are trying to push/present two view controllers onto the stack at almost the same time.